# StoryBoard DoubleAnimation huge CPU usage

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5

Have TextBlock with DoubleAnimation in StoryBoard.
On Windows 7 - **1-2%** CPU usage all the time.
On Windows XP SP3 - **10-15%** CPU usage.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" PreviewMouseDown="incomMessages_SelectionChanged">
     <TextBlock.Text>
          <Binding Mode="OneTime" Converter="{StaticResource Converter}" ConverterParameter="NameAndId"/>
     </TextBlock.Text>
     <TextBlock.Style>
          <Style>    
               <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Value="True">
                         <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                              <BeginStoryboard Name="Blink">
                                   <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:01" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                               </BeginStoryboard>
                          </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                     </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
     </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Am i doing something wrong or it is WPF feature?

Comment: This might be because hardware acceleration is limited / non-existent on XP for WPF: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2007/01/05/comparing-wpf-on-windows-vista-v-windows-xp.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the [RenderCapability.Tier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rendercapability.tier.aspx) property. It indicates the rendering tier for the current thread

> `RenderCapability.Tier = 0` means no graphics hardware acceleration is
>   available for the application on the device. All graphics features use
>   software acceleration.

If `RenderCapability.Tier` is 0 you could change the [Storyboard.DesiredFrameRate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.desiredframerate.aspx) property. The default value is 60 but on Windows XP you could set it lower.

For how to do you can have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henryh/archive/2006/08/23/719568.aspx)